# How to get isLiked the post or not in NodeJs Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, nodes, psql

I'm new to NodeJs.

I'm using PostgreSql and Express to create backend on node. The Data model's are as follow.

UserModel.js

```
const UserModel = sequelize.define(
  "user",
  {
    ID: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    UID: { type: Sequelize.STRING(10), allowNull: false, primaryKey: true },
    name: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
    contact: { type: Sequelize.STRING(10), allowNull: false },
    dob: { type: Sequelize.DATEONLY, allowNull: false },
    profile_image: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
});

UserModel.hasMany(PostModel, { foreignKey: "userId" });
PostModel.belongsTo(UserModel, { foreignKey: "userId", allowNull: false });
UserModel.hasMany(LikeModel, { foreignKey: "userId" });
LikeModel.belongsTo(UserModel, { foreignKey: "userId", allowNull: false });
```

PostModel.js

```
const PostModel = sequelize.define("posts", {
  ID: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
  },
  PID: { type: Sequelize.STRING(15), allowNull: false, primaryKey: true },
  title: { type: Sequelize.TEXT, allowNull: false },
  description: { type: Sequelize.TEXT, allowNull: false },
});

PostModel.hasMany(LikeModel, { foreignKey: "postId" });
LikeModel.belongsTo(PostModel, { foreignKey: "postId", allowNull: false });
```

LikesModel.js

```
const LikeModel = sequelize.define("likes", {
  ID: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  userId: { type: Sequelize.STRING(10), allowNull: false },
});
```

I'm managing the relation between User table, post table and like table. I'm able to get all the posts with user details and total likes. But I want to get a key as well which tells whether the a specific user liked that post or not `isLiked : true/false` for each post.

```
const tlsPosts = await PostModel.findAll({
    order: [["createdAt", "DESC"]],
    limit: 25,
    offset: index === 1 ? 0 : index * 25,
    where: { userId: "TMLKSH" },
    include: [
      {
        model: UserModel
      },
      { model: LikeModel },
    ],
  });
```

What I'm getting

```
{
    "posts": [
      {
        "ID": 2,
        "desc": "wertyuiop[]",
        "createdAt": "2022-12-31T05:14:25.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-12-31T05:29:48.133Z",
        "userId": "ID-567hjk",
        "likes": [
          {
            "ID": 3,
            "userId": "ID-567hjk"
          },
          {
            "ID": 3,
            "userId": "ID-898ghj"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

What I want

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "ID": 2,
      "desc": "wertyuiop[]",
      "createdAt": "2022-12-31T05:14:25.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2022-12-31T05:29:48.133Z",
      "userId": "ID-567hjk",
      "isLiked": true,
      "likes": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks

I tried a lot of things but they didn't work, like I can use loop as well. But I want an optimized approach and code for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const tlsPosts = await PostModel.findAll({
  where: { },
  attributes: {
    include: [
      [
        // Note this sequlize is an instance of connection.
        // so import from connection config not from Sequlize library
        sequelize.literal(
          `( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes 
            WHERE likes."postId" = posts."ID"
            AND likes."userId" = '${userId}'
          )`
        ),
        'isLiked'
      ], [
        Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('likes.postId')),
        'totalLikes'
      ],
    ],
  },
  include: [
    {
      model: LikeModel,
      attributes: [],
      required: false,
      right: false
    },
  ],
  offset: index === 1 ? 0 : index * 25,
  order: [["createdAt", "DESC"]],
  group: [
    'posts.ID',
    "posts.PID",
  ],
  subQuery: false,
  limit: 25,
});

result = {
  "data": [
    {
      "ID": 4,
      "PID": "PID2-UID-2",
      "title": "Demo Title2 For UID1",
      "description": "Demo Description",
      "createdAt": "2023-02-28T04:50:33.548Z",
      "updatedAt": "2023-02-28T04:50:33.548Z",
      "userId": 2,
      "totalLikes": "2",
      "isLiked": "0"
    }, {
      "ID": 1,
      "PID": "PID1-UID-1",
      "title": "Demo Title1 For UID1",
      "description": "Demo Description",
      "createdAt": "2023-02-28T04:50:33.548Z",
      "updatedAt": "2023-02-28T04:50:33.548Z",
      "userId": 1,
      "totalLikes": "3",
      "isLiked": "0"
    },
  ]
}
```

Value of `isLiked` would be `1` or `0` for true, false